# Can't sign-in caused by MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I'm using Office 365 Business Premium for my test. From a couple of days ago, I've gotten prompt for Authentication code (see below) after enter my password when I try to sign-in.

[MFA prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/surkA.png)

It seems like MFA became enabled suddenly although I didn't anything such a configuration. I doubt my account is possibly violated.

Is there any way to recovery from this situation?

Thanks

Kaypyosh

Comment: If you are an administrator, first check if MFA is enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to check it but I can't because I can't sign-in Azure portal by the MFA prompt. In this case, is there something what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you lost your phone you will need to reach out to your administrator to reset your information.

The Authenticator app is designed so that you have to prove your identity, so it will require the admin reset if Authenticator MFA is enforced.

If you are the only global admin on the tenant then you can reach the Azure data protection team to get this resolved.

Azure Data Protection number (866-807-5850)

However, if there is a second global admin you will need to reach out to that person to reset the settings. Please refer to this [similar one](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/54409)

Comment: I really appreciate it. Unfortunately that is the only global admin that I have. I don't know why I have been able to access my portal without MFA prompt before last week and I don't remember that I do such a configuration but anyway I understand there is no way to sign-in without calling the number you told me. Many thanks. Kaypyosh

Answer (score 0):

Only the global admin is able to set up or modify MFA.

You can turn off MFA by following the steps:

> 1.Go to the Office 365 admin center.
>
> 2.Go to Users > Active users.
>
> 3.Choose More > Setup Azure multi-factor auth.
>
> 4.Check your account.
>
> 5.Click Disable on the right.

Please check  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/security-and-compliance/set-up-multi-factor-authentication?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to check it but I can't because I can't sign-in Azure portal by the MFA prompt. In this case, is there anything what I can do?